# Draw Point on Map Without Border

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap)
data <- read.table(file = "data.txt", sep = ",", col.names = c("lat", "lon", "place_name"), fill=FALSE, strip.white=TRUE)

# getting the map
mapgilbert <- get_map(location = c(lon = mean(data$lon), lat = mean(data$lat)),
              zoom = "auto" , maptype = "roadmap", scale = 2, color = "bw")

# plotting the map with some points on it
ggmap(mapgilbert, extent = "device") +
  geom_point(data = data, aes(x = lon, y = lat, fill = place_name), size = 0.5, shape = 22) +
  guides(fill=FALSE, alpha=FALSE, size=FALSE)
```

This will produce points with different color (According to their names). Something like this:

[image]

However, I want to **get rid of the black border of the points**. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I think you need to play with stroke, e.g. stroke = 5 or stroke = 0 ?

Comment: Please get used to provide reproducible code in order to make it easier for visitors & readers. (For instance, `data` is missing, which could be added by using `dput(data)` or by creating a dummy data frame.)

Comment: @lukeA You are right. I didn't think of that. Sorry!

Comment: ggplot authors (sneakily - hey, why not? It's my package!) changed the default plotting symbol from 16 (filled circle _without_ border) to 19 (filled circle _with_ border) a few versions back. Imagine R core changing the default plotting symbol from 1 to 11. There would be pandemonium in the streets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try a different `shape`:

```
data <- data.frame(lat=52.5176736, lon=13.3895097)
library(ggmap)
library(ggplot2)
mapgilbert <- get_map(location = c(lon = mean(data$lon), lat = mean(data$lat)),
              zoom = "auto" , maptype = "roadmap", scale = 2, color = "bw")
ggmap(mapgilbert, extent = "device") +
  geom_point(data = data, aes(x = lon, y = lat), size = 6, shape = 16, color="red") +
  guides(fill=FALSE, alpha=FALSE, size=FALSE)
```

or set `color` to `NA` when using `shape = 21`:

```
ggmap(mapgilbert, extent = "device") +
  geom_point(data = data, aes(x = lon, y = lat), size = 6, shape = 21, color=NA, fill = "red") +
  guides(fill=FALSE, alpha=FALSE, size=FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: But how to allow for different color. Your code will paint them all as red. Changing the shape value in my code made all points "black"!

Comment: Use `geom_point(data = data, aes(x = lon, y = lat, color = place_name), size = 6, shape = 16)`, to map `place_name` to the color aesthetic.